# How to write JSON requests using django

Tags: python, django

I want to write google places api like web service for learning. I have started with  django python and searched for how to write api style responses. I found django-tastypie, but this framework looks for different thing, most examples given for database interaction. What I need is given ' xxx.yy/api/places?lat=A&lng=B ' URL, respond with places in 100m using json format. I am new to this world, please provide with examples and links.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not suited for this kind of very broad question. We have no idea, what you really need and trying to find that out and then answering would roughly be equivalent with writing a whole book. Please play with Django first on your own, read some booms or tutorials, start small. If you have a specific and narrowly defined question later, please ask it here. But right now, your question is about to be unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should learn the connection between URL and Django python scripts
Visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/
about JSON format you can use

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype="application/json")
```